# How do I reach this harmonic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, harmonic-functions

I have the following equality:

$$\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x \tag{1}$$

and I know that this must give me :

$$x= A cos(\omega t) + B sin(\omega t) \tag{2}$$

How do I reach this result? What happens if I add an extra term which depends on the variable $(t)$ , eg. $x^2 = -\omega^2 x + bt$?

Comment: As a physics-related aside, such a differential equation (with the extra $bt$ term) represents a driven harmonic oscillator. A physical interpretation can be found, for example, in John Taylor’s classical mechanics textbook.

Comment: Would the last equation in the example also be related to harmonic oscillators?

Comment: The first equation is an undriven harmonic oscillator (no applied force), and the last is a driven harmonic oscillator (time-dependent applied force).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite as

$$x''+\omega^2 x. = 0$$

Multiply both sides by $2x'$

$$2x'x'' + 2\omega^2xx' = 0$$

$$(x'^2 + \omega^2x^2)' = 0$$

Can you proceed from here?